# Swagger Springfox - how to generate schema type array for query param List<String>

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I am using springfox version 3.0.0 and using OAS annotations.

I need to produce fragment like this (with schema type array) in Swagger JSON for my method:

```
"parameters":[
   {
      "name":"ids",
      "in":"query",
      "description":"multiple ids",
      "required":true,
      "schema":{
         "uniqueItems":true,
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"string"
         }
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

Which produces desired parameter component in Swagger UI:
[image: Schema type array for parameter in Swagger UI]

However, I am not able to get this Swagger JSON (and Swagger UI appearance of the parameter) with any of the available Swagger annotations.
Currently I have code like this in my controller (btw, this works like a charm with the springdoc library, which we have used before we have migrated to springfox):

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;

@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

  @Operation(summary = "Return list of...")
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success")
  @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public List<SomeDTO> getSomethingByIds(@Parameter(description = "List of ids") @RequestParam("ids") Set<String> ids) {
    ...
  }
```

But I have also experimented with setting schema of the `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter` annotation manually (like `@Parameter(description = "List of ids", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class))))` ).

Also tried to experiment with older (non OAS) Swagger annotations - like `io.swagger.annotations.ApiImplicitParam` or `io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam`.

Also tried changing of the `Set<String>` type to `List<String>` or `String[]`.

 No success with neither of these, no matter what I have tried, springfox always produces Swagger JSON fragment like this (with schema type string) and therefore just simple string input in swagger UI:

```
"parameters":[
   {
      "name":"ids",
      "in":"query",
      "description":"List of ids",
      "required":true,
      "style":"form",
      "explode":true,
      "schema":{
         "type":"string"
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

Anyone had better luck with this?

Comment: did you resolve this somehow? I have the same problem

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
@Parameter(name = "languages", in = QUERY, array = @ArraySchema( schema = @Schema(type = "string")))
```

Comment: this solution do not work for me with springfox 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen, put the request params inside an object as below :

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/filter")
   public ResponseEntity filterValues(RequestFilter requestFilter) {
```

```
public class RequestFilter {
    private List<String> filters;
    private List<Long> ids;
}
```

The rendered swagger operation is :

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Spring-Fox 3.0.0. Furthermore it requeres an editor implementation to convert Strings to RequestFilter instances