# Springfox-oas not generating array type query parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a very simple REST API (Spring-Boot) which should accept a list of strings as query parameters:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get the value drivers for a part by its as JSON output")
@GetMapping(AppConstants.VDJSON)
ValueDriver getValueDriverJson(
        @RequestParam(value="pnrList")
        final ArrayList<String> pnrList);
```

This generates a swagger output like this:

```
"/vdbptool/api/v1/vdjson": {

"get": {
    "tags": [
        "value-driver-codes-controller"
    ],
    "summary": "Get the value drivers for a part by its PNR in LIST format as JSON output",
    "operationId": "getValueDriverJsonUsingGET",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "pnrList",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "pnrList",
            "required": true,
            "style": "form",
            "explode": true,
            "schema": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    ],.
```

in swagger ui this looks like

[image]

The problem seems to be the type of the parameter, which is "string" instead of "array" - whatever I have tried.

Expected Output:
[image]

My Gradle:

```
dependencies {

...

implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-oas:3.0.0'
```

What am I missing here in order to get the proper parameter type ("array") generated into the OAS 3.0 spec via Springfox ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. Thanks to this guide: https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html I have easily changed from SpringFox to Openapi-ui.
Gradle:

```
    //implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    //implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-oas:3.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
```

Output now:

[image]

And:

[image]

So, I assume that SpringFox is slightly outdated, last changes almost three years ago:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Spring specifically, you have to use the more generic `List<String>` for it to interpret your parameter as an array of strings. Technically, there is no difference between `List<String>` and `ArrayList<String>`, but Spring chooses to use `List<String>`.

So your code should be updated to:

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "Get the value drivers for a part by its as JSON output")
@GetMapping(AppConstants.VDJSON)
ValueDriver getValueDriverJson(
        @RequestParam(value="pnrList")
        final List<String> pnrList);
```

So your Swagger output should then be:

```json
"/vdbptool/api/v1/vdjson": {

"get": {
    "tags": [
        "value-driver-codes-controller"
    ],
    "summary": "Get the value drivers for a part by its PNR in LIST format as JSON output",
    "operationId": "getValueDriverJsonUsingGET",
"parameters": [
        {
            "name": "pnrList",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "pnrList",
            "required": true,
            "style": "form",
            "explode": true,
            "schema": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Actually, `List<String>` represents anything that implements `List`, including, but not limited to `ArrayList<String>`. Hence, there are obvious technical differences between the two. If you implement `List` as a new class of your own, then you will be able to use that instead of `ArrayList` as your object.

Comment: Good info @LajosArpad

Comment: Already tested with SpringFox: List, ArrayList: same result, Springfox renders a string type, not an array of strings.

Comment: @AxelAmthor - Does this help https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3629#issuecomment-1368022213

Comment: @djmonki Thanks, but actually I have tested that as well. It doesn't work, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214455/swagger-springfox-how-to-generate-schema-type-array-for-query-param-liststrin?rq=1